# javascript: get value of `this` when calling function with apply

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, call

When I call

```
var fun = function(input) {
  console.log(!!this, this, typeof(this), Object.keys(this), !this.toString(), this.constructor.name); 
  // logs: true [Boolean: false] object [] false Boolean
  if(!this) return input;
  return this;
}
var someVar = false;
var result = fun.apply(someVar, ["TEST"]);
```

I would expect the result to be "TEST", but the result is a strange object printed in the console as [Boolean: false].

**The question is, what is the most elegant way to check inside the function if `this` (passed in as `someVar`) has some kind of falsy value so that "TEST" would be returned in this example?**

The code is running in node js.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in your function so that its `this` value does not get coerced to an object:

```js
var fun = function(input) {
  "use strict";
  console.log(!!this, this, typeof this);
  if (!this) return input;
  return this;
}
var someVar = false;
var result = fun.call(someVar, "TEST");
```